# Standardize dirty images by pre-processing for OCR

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, python-tesseract, image-thresholding

I'm working on a project to study the problem faced in OCR'ing images from different sources however this question is limited to camera captured images. samples are from books , question papers etc

What I'm looking for is a way by which I can make the images OCR ready.

source: https://ibb.co/Q8qWWZm

Some of the methods that I have tried

```
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

output : https://ibb.co/nR4kcsP (compressed due to large size)

after threshold I have tried median blur with kernel size 9 which removed almost all of the noises but damaged some characters too.

output: https://ibb.co/TBF5Fs4

The other method that I have tried is use skimage (local threshold) :

```
warped = cv2.cvtColor(imgc, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
T = threshold_local(warped, 11, offset = 1, method = "gaussian")
warped = (warped > T).astype("uint8") * 255
cv2.imwrite('newth.jpg', warped)
```

this method generates to much noises but, that to can be cleared using median blur also damages some characters.

Am I doing it the right way?
If not then what should I do and what should I do next. My goal is the find a method which works on all the images with maximum accuracy preferably 100%

Comment: usually each image is a special case in terms of noise, there is no general solution, but do you still need a solution for better processing of this text?

Comment: for this specific image you can use : `img[img[...,0]>130] = 255` then `_,th = cv2.threshold(img,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

Comment: What I need is a way to standardize the images to attain maximum results not 100% but as maximum as posible. So that I can show in the study that it requires ML or neural networks to obtain 100% accuracy.

Comment: You might as well want to try Otsu Threshold. But as @BelalHomaidan said, there is no general solution for all. One thing you can do is to have a set of methods that can work on any image and apply all of them to each image you encounter. Pick the best one. Of course, it is not the best method considering the time taken. For that, you can parallel processing.